# Openshift online - how to define and use image pull secret

Tags: openshift

I would like to create an image pull secret for an image saved on dockerhub. However, it does not work for me. I suspect the error on one of the following spots:

1. Registry server address - I used https://registry.hub.docker.com. But I am unsure how to tell the system the name of the image on dockerhub
2. When deploying the image to my Openshift project, I am being asked for an image name. What should I enter here? The name of the image pull secret?

Thank you.

Comment: What's the web console URL?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could find a way which works for me:
1/ the repo server address is https://index.docker.io
2/ I have to pull the image by /